# class default output value

Tags: python, class

I would like to create a class that can output a value without having to specify an attribute. How can I do this?

**analogous to**

```
 >>> class my_class:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self = value

 >>> a = my_class(4)
 >>> a * 3
 12
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: `self = value` makes no sense. `self` is just local variable in the function, assigning it doesn't actually change the object.

Comment: There's a difference between class attributes/methods and instance attributes/methods.  I'm _guessing_ that's what you intend.

Comment: @Barmar I realize that `__init__` and `self = value` wouldn't work, I did however think that the syntax I'm looking for would be somewhat similar, such as using a different method such as `__repr__` or `__call__` . Am I wrong?

Comment: [guide to Python magic methods](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/)

Comment: @roganjosh you may be right, I'm not sure. I thought I understood the principles behind class/instance attributes and methods, but I didn't see how it would relate to this task. Would you mind sharing a good link?

Comment: I don't think there's any magic method that would do this for all contexts. If you want it to work for multiplication you define `__mul__`, but then you also need to define `__add__` and `__sub__`, etc.

Comment: @roganjosh I don't think that's what he's intending. He doesn't want to have to refer to a method or attribute at all, he wants the object to behave like the underlying value.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, in this question I had hoped to find a way to have an object output a default value when called without an attribute, simmilar to the way when I create a pd.DataFrame object, simply calling the object outputs a data frame, and I can modify that entire object without calling an attribute, only in my case it would be for much simpler uses. But if there is no simple solution then thank you!

Comment: @roganjosh your first question: "why would I want to do this"...
I'm actually working on a chemistry program/class, where I can give an object attributes of volume, mass etc.. but then also be able to output each attribute in different units. This question was a 'side-quest'. I'll link you to that one once its up, if you care to offer advice. Thank you!!

Comment: _Attributes_ of class instances can have default values, which is useful in cases where there are well-known and expected default values. What you're trying to do, by itself, seems like a questionable idea, and it sounds like understanding the problem you're trying to solve with this would let us suggest a better approach.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly my thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `__mul__`, `__add__`, etc. [methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) so that the class responds as desired to those operations.

Here is an example that will just work with the `__mul__` methods.

```
>>> class my_class():
...     def __init__(self, value):
...             self.value = value
...     def __mul__(self, n):
...             return self.value * n
... 
>>> a = my_class(4)
>>> a * 3
12
```